# How to get each items height in a ListView

Tags: android, listitem

How to get each items height in a ListView, as each item in the ListView has different size(as items are wrapped to content)
i want to compress all the different item height to same item height on pinch in?

Comment: You should narrow down your technologies. ListView and ListItem are fairly ubiquitous. I'm *guessing* from your mention of "pinch in" that you're talking about Android programming. Yes?

Comment: sorry about that..YES in android programming..
All the items will be in different heights when i pinch in ..All items should become two liner..giving preview of each item..